# Force font to computer modern (serif) in math mode although it is set to sans serif

Tags: fonts, math-mode, sans-serif

I set my font to sans serif via

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet,sfmath}
```

Now I want to use some symbols -not all- (only normal letters or greek letters) from the standard computer modern math font in mathmode.

Unfortunatly neither

```
$\mathrm{w}$
```

nor

```
{\fontfamily{cmm}\selectfont $w$}
```

will give me the desired result.

I want to use it in a `tikz`-environment, but I guess that's no difference to the usual usage.

update:
I am a little confused about the fact, that I cannot change the font at all. Neither with the above mentioned `selectfont`-command nor in `tikz` via (for example)

```
\node[font=\rmfamily] at (0,0) {$w$};
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example using `\mathrm` seems to work nicely in MikTeX 2.9 with a `tikz`-box:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\mycolorbox}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle,inner xsep=10pt,inner ysep=10pt,
          anchor=south,text width=\columnwidth,shade]{#1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[mathrmOrig]{sfmath}

\begin{document}
sans serif text

\mycolorbox{Sans serif: $a + b$, CM: {$\mathrm{c}$}}

\end{document}
```

I think you need to explicitly enable this with the `mathrmOrig` option in `sfmath`. The result looks like this:

[image: TeX example rendered]

Comment: This works also for me with TexLive 2011 with pdflatex.

Comment: Thanks, that also works in TexLive2010. But is there a solution to get the computer modern math font (cmm) working, too?