# Locally change font style from sfmath to amsmath

Tags: fonts, math-mode, amsmath

I am using the package `sfmath`. It is rather hard to explain why, but the reason should not matter for my question. If it is  required I can try to explain why I need `sfmath`. Nevertheless, the main message is that it can not be turned off.

Although I am using `sfmath`, I do would like to use the typical "a" in the mathmode of `amsmath`. How can I achieve this?

Is it possible to change the font style for single words/letter such that I, per command, can change the font style locally when required?

For illustration purposes a simple working example looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 a = a
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`sfmath` seems to be overruling `amsmath` as it does not produce the "a" that I would like. The code above results in:

[image]

Whereas the lower "a = a" is obtained by turning off `sfmath` in order to illustrate the "a" that I would like to include.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42394/39222 help?

Comment: Yes and no, I mean it does allow me to locally change the font. However it does not result in the required "a" which `amsmath` produces. I am not sure how to alter the answer of the link you gave me to my specific case.

Comment: In that case, please provide a small but complete document illustrating the issue to encourage people to help you and to help them understand your situation. (This is known locally as a 'Minimal Working Example' and should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.)

Comment: I am not sure how to include a image of the pdf I am producing. I guess my "hack" will suffice.

Comment: There may be some confusion over terminology: While `sfmath` is a package that provides a certain sans-serif font for math mode, this is *not* the purpose of `amsmath`. The macros and environments of the `amsmath` package are compatible with all sorts of font families, including those provided by `sfmath`. Thus, it doesn't make much sense to say that `amsmath` overrules `sfmath`, or vice versa. Are you really looking to use the serif-style `a` of either Computer Modern Roman or Computer Modern math italics instead of the sans-serif `a` that's activated when `sfmath` is loaded?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand what you'd like to achieve. Do you want that all a's in math mode are in normal math italic?

Comment: What I want to achieve is the following: while `sfmath` is active I want to use the font of `sfmath`. However I want to locally be able to use the "a" as produced by `amsmath` (lower "a" in the figure included).

Comment: @TheDude - The issue is that `amsmath` does not "produce", or otherwise make available, any particular font.

Comment: @Mico, `amsmath` left aside. How can I locally change the font of my "a" to the one at the bottom of the included image?

Answer (score 2):

Well you either can define a mathcommand that switches to the standard font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathori}    {letters}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 a = \mathori{a}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You can also reset the font for the "a" back to "normal" (this doesn't work "locally"):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`a}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 a = a
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments in `sfmath.sty`:

> ```
> % After including the package sfmath.sty, all maths of the current
> % document is displayed with sans serif fonts; there is no way to
> % switch back to the original behavior.
> ```

The style works by overwriting all the standard math font commands, and so does not leave access to the original math fonts.  Those fonts are computer modern or latin modern by default.  As many have pointed out in comments, `amsmath` is not a font changing package, it has a close cousin `amsfonts` which is, but it mostly provides extra symbols on top of the computer modern ones.

A package that will provide you with a form of sans serif math and allow switching is `sansmath`.  Here is a small sample:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  a = a \ne \mathsf{a}
\end{equation}

\begin{sansmath}
  \begin{equation}
    a = a \ne \mathsf{a} \ne \mathit{a}
  \end{equation}
\end{sansmath}

\end{document}
```

Note how you can use `\mathit` to get the standard `a`.

You should also look at this discussion: [Typeset mathematical symbols also in sans serif font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24035/15925)